# Does this numeronym abbreviation syntax have a specific name?

Tags: abbreviations

Is there a name for the type of numeronym abbreviation that has the first and last letters with the count of the missing letters in between?

Some examples:

- **l10n** - *localization*
- **p13n** - *personalization*
- **g11n** - *globalization*
- **i18n** - *internationalization*
- **a16z** - *Andreessen Horowitz*

As you can see, most of my examples of this usage relate directly to [internationalization and localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization).

Comment: It looks like the answer is *there isn't a specific name*.  It's just another lonely unclassified numeronym.  I imagine due to obvious usage limitations, it's not likely to get its own name anytime soon.

Comment: Maybe we invent a name: *medial count substitution*  (m21n)